# Nginx: Add trailing slash to specific URL only

Tags: redirect, nginx

I am trying to redirect the following URL by adding a trailing slash

```
http://mywebsite.com/download (main CMS will take over to show page not found)
```

to

```
http://mywebsite.com/download/ (another standalone script will take over in this folder)
```

I tried to search on the Internet and although there are plenty of info for adding trailing slashes for all URLs in the site, I ONLY WANT to add to the "download" segment, but can't find any info on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following line to your config file. `return 301 http://$host$uri/ ;` in location /download part.
like below

```
location /download {
  return 301 http://$host$uri/ ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I have changed https to $scheme: return 301 $scheme://$host$uri/;